# Vue.js render previous chat messages without changing the postition of current messages on screen

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I use `v-for` to render the message list. when the first batch of messages are rendered, I use `scrollIntoView()` on the newest one so the container scrolls to bottom. as the user scrolls up I fetch previous messages to create a seamless scroll.
the problem is that when new messages are rendered, the scroll goes to the top of the container.

I tried saving the first message id in the list before updating the list with fetched messages and then scrolling back to that message but it causes a jump on the screen for a moment and is not a good user experience.

how can I prepend and render older messages to the message list so that current messages stay in their place wherever they are on the screen?

message list is stores in vuex and I update it using this action:

```
HandleMessageList({state, commit}, msgList) {
    const currentMessages = state.messages
    const updatedMessages = msgList.concat(currentMessages)
    commit('SET_MESSAGES', updatedMessages)
}
```

and in template:

```
<template>
  <div class=msg-container" ref="messageDisplayArea">
    <message-object
      v-for="msg in msgList"
      :key="msg.id"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapState} from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "MessageDisplay",
  components: {
    MessageObject,
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      msgList: state => state.messages,
    }),
  },
  updated() {
    this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToTarget())
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.messageDisplayArea.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleUserScroll)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.$refs.messageDisplayArea.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleUserScroll)
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToTarget() {
       // ... scroll back to the position before message list update
    },
    handleUserScroll(e) {
      const scrollTop = e.target.scrollTop
      const scrollHeight = e.target.scrollHeight
      const elementHeight = e.target.offsetHeight
      if (scrollTop === 0 && elementHeight < scrollHeight) {
        // ... fetch older messages
      }
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

versions:

```
vue 2.6.10
vuex 3.0.1
```

Comment: if I've got you right here (with a playground that would be more comfortable), the issue is in your scroll handler I suppose. It must be tied to the height not sufficient for the next tick or something - just a guess here. Just to check the theory make extra space and check if it jumps

Comment: @midnight_dev thank you for your participation. the scroll handler scrolls to the target correctly. the jump occurs because of the change in the scroll position after v-for is done and then going back with scroll handler. it would be better to solve it without going to the top of the container in the first place. I think there might be a setting to prevent this behavior in Vue, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the behavior I wanted in this [Quasar component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/infinite-scroll#example--reverse-messenger-style-)

it is an infinite scroll component but the main part is that the scroll can be in reverse which is necessary for a chat message scroll.